# Copy the files from docker container to host using a volume mount , while starting the container

Tags: docker

I want to copy the files from docker container to host using a docker volume mount. How to give the docker run command in such a way that the files from a respective folder in docker container gets copied to my volume or host.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your source is a docker volume; if it weren't, the files would already be on your local file system:

```sh
SRC=[[VOL-NAME]] # i.e. you can `docker volume inspect ${VOLUME}`
DST=[[DIR-NAME]] # full (!) path to where you want the files

FILE="something.txt" # Or whatever

docker run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
--volume=${SRC}:/tmp/src \
--volume=${DST}:/tmp/dst \
busybox sh -c "cp /tmp/src/${FILE} /tmp/dst && ls -la /tmp/dst"

ls -la ${DST}
something.txt
```